# Deleted system files in fonts folder, can't put them back

Tags: macos, terminal

My friend decided to pull a prank on my computer the other day and I decided to return the favor. I came across a the idea to remove the files in his files in the `/Volumes/System/Library/Fonts` folder.

Before I did this, just in case, I copied the folder and put it in a folder on my computer over the network. The moment he noticed that nothing was working he restarted his computer.

We are no longer able to successfully boot up the computer and I came across a post that it's easily fixable in Single-User mode.

- While working on the terminal I have been trying many things but have been unable to do so.
- We have tried to copy the files from the recycle bin, and paste them back in their original folder but have been unable to do so since the files are all read only system files.
- I also considered my backup plan(Since I still have all the original files on my computer but he doesn't share his network nor does he have an Ethernet port.
- I also considered grabbing a getting a USB drive to add the files or even restore them from the recycle bin. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine or download the latest [Combo update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581) and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Single user mode on a Mac mounts the root drive read-only by default. If the system isn't letting you write stuff, that's probably why, not any permissions or "system files" problem (you're running as root, which has access to everything).

Once you're in single user mode,

```
mount -uw /
```

should make it writeable.